# Using Unity IOC Container in ASP.net solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, inversion-of-control, unity-container

We are using Microsofts Unity IOC container in an ASP.Net solution.

In one of the top layers we use the RegisterInstance method. We then get it back lower down with the Resolve method.

While looking at another problem we have seen that ASP.Net has thread agility, that is that a request can jump threads.

So the question is if we register an instance on one thread, and the request jumps thread before we resolve the instance, will we get back the correct instance?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.lifetimemanager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you resolve your type on same container you've registered it in (or its child), you'll get correct instance.
2. As far as I know there's no need to register types in container on every request, that's usually done somewhere on application start.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/27496)

> [...] **Resolve, ResolveAll, and BuildUp are all thread safe**. Looks like
>   we missed it in the docs.
>
> None of the other methods on the container are thread safe, so if
>   you're going to be configuring containers, you'll need to do locking.
>   Also, if you've got one thread configuring and another thread
>   resolving, there will be thread issues.

AFAIK, your approach is correct and you shouldn't worry about getting incorrect instance in ASP.NET application.